# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements when upload binary

Tags: ios, icloud

I can't publish my new application with icloud support. It's rejected as "Invalid binary" and I receive an email with:

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle
>   contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the
>   com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement, the
>   first value in the array must consist of the prefix provided by Apple
>   in the provisioning profile followed by a bundle identifier suffix.
>   The bundle identifier must match the bundle identifier for one of your
>   apps or another app that you are permitted to use as the iCloud
>   container identifier.
>
> Specifically, value "LHDZF28764.net.sverin.namnkallan.icloud" for key
>   "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" in Namnkallan is
>   not supported.

I looked at other similar questions, but they have wildcard indentifier. The bundle indentifier is net.sverin.namnkallan. I tried to remove icloud from the indentifier and checked the Team ID in the Member Center.

If I disable icloud support in the provisioning portal for the app, I can't upload the binary at all without deleting the icloud support.

Is it an coincident that my App ID has the same prefix as my Team ID. My other App ID's have a different prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the two identifiers must be identical, if on is com.companyname.appname then the other must also be com.companyname.appname
I am surprised that you are even able to build when they dont match